# React Hooks: Make useEffect run when location.search changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to make a useEffect fire every time the query params of my URL changes, this is the format of the URL:

```
https://localhost:3000/main/persons?results=1
```

In my code I have the following:

```
const location = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
      console.log('Location update')
    }, [location]);
```

However, my problem is that the useEffect is only run when the location.pathname changes, and not when the query parameters of the URL changes (?results=1). I have also tried the following logic: [location.pathname, location.search] but with no luck.

Do anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: Where did you save `result` value ? If you save it in a state, you can pass it as dependency in useEffect hook `useEffect(() => {}, [resultState])`

Answer (score 5):

Try doing this:

```
const { pathName } = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Location update')
}, [pathName]);
```

Similarly for location.search

Answer (score 3):

For URL params use useParams in your hook

```
let { results} = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
      console.log('Params updated',results)
    }, [results]);
```